# Ring tone super-quiet on Galaxy S9+

Tags: ringtone, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I am having a problem with my ringtone on my Galaxy S9+.

Suddenly, my ringtone has become extremely soft - as if it was on the lowest possible setting (except mute).

However, it is on the highest, so it's definitely not a problem with the setting.

It is not a problem with the speaker because I hear well during calls or watching videos.
Furthermore, when I select the ringtone to change it, the sample play is perfect.
It is only when someone tries to phone that the problem occurs.

I have tried restarting the phone, going into safe made and many other things and can't seem to solve the problem.
It's almost as if it thinks it is sending the ringing to my air-pods. However, the bluetooth is turned off so it is definitely not connected.

Until recently it was only intermittent but now it is happening all the time.

It also happens with incoming WhatsApp calls.

I am using an mp3 for my ringtone but it happens also with build-in tones.

```
Software Information:
Android 10
Baseband version: G965FXXU8DTC5
Kernel Version: 4.9.118-18339721
Build: QP1A.190711.020.G965FXXU8DTC5
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested I am posting how it was "resolved".

Went to Samsung and it turns out that the bottom speaker isn't working.

That's why it is so weak. The fact that it works from time to time probably means that the problem corrosion or something similar.

This also explains two other problems I have had that I thought were unconnected:
The "beep" when plugged in (as I mentioned in the question)
The fact than when I am speaker lift at to my ear I can no longer hear the call. I guess that the sound then comes out only the bottom speaker.

Edit:
It turns out that it rings when flat on a surface only. It seems that when it is vertical it tries to ring from the top and bottom whereas when flat it only rings from the top.